# Can I "reset" the story on a character that has completed it?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been playing Diablo 3 with friends and have been annoyed that they feel the need to rush through and skip dialogue. I see that I can go back to Act 1 and start again so that I catch the story, but I also see that followers and lore books (in particular) remain with me.

Is there a way to "reset" the story without starting another character?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158500/what-does-reset-quests-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, you can go back to the starting quests. This can be done from the main character selection screen, under "Change Quest".

However, you were asking specifically about lore books. I don't think there is a way to reset all the lore books.

Instead, you can open up your <kbd>J</kbd>ournal and look through there. It contains all the Lore books, monster entries, etc. for your reading or listening pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

On the character screen, under "Resume Quest" is a button called "Game Settings".  In there is the option to choose where you want to start, along with a "Reset Quests" button.  That will start you right back at the beginning of the story, in Act 1, and remove all other quest starting points until you reach them again.

Keep in mind, though, that any lore books you already have won't drop again; any that you need, though, such as Leah's and Cain's, will be available at the appropriate points in the Act.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this **AND** be able to pick up all the lore books in sequence again is to create a new hero. Since you have 9 character slots, I would suggest that you dedicate one to soloing. By doing this, you can play the game at your own pace and enjoy all the lore.

Co-op is fun, and is great for the camaraderie, but it's important to group with people who share your playstyle.

What makes D3 fun, is you can solo the whole game, and therefore soak everything in at your leisure... or not.