# What does the "reset quests" option do?

Tags: diablo-iii

The latest patch introduced a "Reset Quests" option which seems to clear all quest progress and restart the campaign. However, I have it available on some characters and not others. Also, I'm not entirely clear on how this is different than simply changing which quest or act I'm on and setting it back to the beginning of Act 1, other than the fact that it wipes all other progress.

What exactly does Reset Quests do and why would I want to use it rather than just changing my progress point back to the beginning of Act 1?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67609/can-i-reset-the-story-on-a-character-that-has-completed-it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**What does the "Reset Quests" option do?**

This option will clear all progress you have made with the character you use it on. You will have to play the storyline again and unlock each quest before you will be able to choose to start at that quest.

**What are the conditions to have the option available?**

To have the option available, your character needs to have completed all quests, including killing Diablo.

If you decide to use the option on a specific character, you will have to complete all the quests again to be able to use it again.

**What are the benefits of resetting quests?**

By resetting your quests, you will re-enable first-time bonus experience & rewards for quests, boss kills and such.

As an example, killing Diablo for the first time currently [guarantees a legendary drop for level 60 characters](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/13183882/patch-203-now-live-3-11-2014##Bosses). This will be re-activated after having reset your quest progress.

Comment: Do you know how this works if someone else joins your game? If they haven't reset, do they get their standard "Done this quest a thousand times" XP while you get the "first time quest" XP?

Comment: I think, yes. As far as I understood, the bonuses are "per character". Players joining your game will have bonuses or not depending on their character progression.

Comment: @astryad Part of your answer got me really excited, the "should be moved to Diablo". But out of curiosity, do you have a source for that? A blue post or pre-patch notes would make me super happy but I do not want to get my hopes up for speculation.

Comment: i've killed diablo and I can't reset my quests...

Comment: [This](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/reset-quests-and-guaranteed-legendary-drops-in-diablo-3-v2) seems to indicate that more than simply killing Diablo is required.

Comment: @z- Did you complete all quests of the storyline ? As stated in Sterno link, killing Diablo is not the sole requirement. You need to complete every quest of the storyline to have the option activated.

Comment: sterno's link is correct you should update your answer since all you state in it is you have to have killed diablo

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reasons you would want to reset quests. Quest rewards after resetting are improved, although I don't know how. Someone will have to science it, whether it's extra exp/gold/items, etc.

Another thing is that resetting quests will net you a guaranteed legendary off of Diablo, the final boss. So by resetting, you can get yourself a legendary (eventually).

Comment: What you're talking about is a bug, post-60 you get a legendary off SK right now which wasn't intended.

Comment: Though with Loot 2.0, if you don't get at least one Legendary in a full playthrough, you might consider serious Karma issues and prayers to the Random Number God...

Comment: @Blindy They said that yes, it's a bug, but when they fix it they'll move that effect to Diablo, so it's still relevant information.